# get data from strongly typed view in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have strongly typed view and I want to get the data in the controller.
This is what I have:

```
@model WordAutomation.Models.Document

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Document";
}

<h2>Document</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Document</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CaseNumber)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CaseNumber)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CaseNumber)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

And then, in the controller I have this:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Document(FormCollection formValue)
        {
            string test = formValue[0].ToString();
            return View();
        }
```

But no data comes up. Any idea what am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Could you add your full view codes?

Comment: @AliRizaAdiyahsi Merhaba AliRiza, pls check now :)

Comment: Why do you post model instead of formCollection like this: `public ActionResult Document(Document model)`

Comment: I m talking about @Terric answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let MVC handle the model binding for you. Instead of passing `FormCollection` to your controller, you can simply pass an instance of your view model. Change your controller action to this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Document(WordAutomation.Models.Document model)
{
    string test = model.CaseNumber;

    return View(model); // return your model back to the view to persist values
}
```

MVC will automatically bind the values in your `FormCollection` to `WordAutomation.Models.Document` for you. Then you can simply pass your model back to the view after POST to persist the input values if desired (have included this in example).

Comment: MVC is so simple and I am making to look much more complex :). Thanks

Comment: @Laziale we've all been there ;o) glad your problem is sorted.

Comment: I wish, I write my comment as answer :) I thought more complex too.

Answer (score 0):

Its is so easy to get data from view to controller when it was strongly typed.
All you need to do is just get the data in controller through model.yourpropertyname.

The code will be look like this in model

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Document(Document aDocumentModel)
    {
        string test = aDocumentModel.CaseNumber;
        return View();
    }
```

Now the data is available in "String test" you can use it where it needed,
and one more thing you need to 
tell you controller about the namespace of "Document"-model so you need to add

```
using WordAutomation.Models;//Your Model's namespace here
```

in the namespace portion of controller.

Hope it helps!!!